# SonarQube: Scanning process ignores lcov.info

Tags: typescript, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

I am scanning a `ui` project.

The source code is in `typescript`.

`gulp test-coverage` generates `.js` files (which are then scanned for coverage). (each `.ts` file gets a `.js` file right next to it, in the same location)

I am pointing the scanner to the `lcov.info` file as follows:

```
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=test-coverage/lcov.info
```

**The problem**:

The `lcov.info`, provides coverage information for `.js` files

For some reason, SonarQube also provides coverage information for the `*.ts` files (although **not** incorporated 
in the test coverage report).

**Why is that?**

If I explicitly use

```
sonar.inclusions=**/*.ts
```

or

```
sonar.language=ts
```

the `.js` files will be ignored from the coverage report

If I use

```
sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/*.ts
```

and no specific inclusions, this will lead to **both** the `.ts` and `.js` files being scanned for errors, which will end up in duplicate errors (after all, `.js` files are generated by their `.ts` counterparts.

Any suggestions?

The whole issue of course would just go away, if sonarqube took litteraly the `lcov.info` and did not take initiatives about scanning other files.)

Answer (score 8):

If your source code is written in TypeScript, the coverage report (`lcov.info`) must contain information about TypeScript files, and not compiled JavaScript. The property you must be using in this case is `sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths`.

You can check out this example (https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarTS-example) to get more details.

Comment: I understand but this does not justify `SonarQube` from trying to provide coverage for files **not** in my `lcov.info`

Comment: If I correctly understand what you're saying, SonarQube automatically sets coverage to 0 for all files that are not included in the report. You can opt-out this behavior by ignoring code coverage on some files (the ones that are not included in the report). See more: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreCodeCoverage

Comment: I actually tried this and it worked. However the problem now became: how **not** to include generated `.js` in the static code analysis (not the coverage report), As I am saying in the question body, using `sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/*.ts` partially solves the problem given that code analysis is done for both `*.ts` and `*.js`, while I want **only** `*.ts`.

Comment: sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths has now been depreciated, use sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths. Reference: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/

Answer (score 3):

All of the following configurations work together, I also need `jest-sonar-reporter` to generate the XML file which sonar requires.

sonar properties

```sh
npm run sonar-scanner -- \
  -Dsonar.sources=./src \
  -Dsonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**/*,**/coverage-reports/** \
  -Dsonar.typescript.exclusions=**/node_modules/** \
  -Dsonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage-reports/lcov.info \
  # be sure to include your test files
  -Dsonar.test.inclusions=**/__test__/*.spec.ts,**/__test__/*.test.ts \
  # generate by jest sonar reporter at <rootDir>
  -Dsonar.testExecutionReportPaths=test-report.xml \ 
  -Dsonar.coverage.exclusions=src/**/*.tsx
```

jest.config.json

```
"testResultsProcessor": "jest-sonar-reporter",
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same kind of issue in my Typescript project also,

In order to implement static code analysis for Typescript & code coverage report for compile Javascript. Configure your sonar properties like the following snippet.

Folder Info, **app** folder contains typescript source files & **build** folder contains compiled Javascript files

```
sonar.sources=app/src/,build/src
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**

#Excluding app folder in code coverage analysis
sonar.coverage.exclusions=app/src/**.ts    
sonar.ts.tslint.configPath=tslint.json
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=reports/lcov.dat
```

As Javascript is used for code coverage, Sonar project has **2 Quality Profile (Javascript and Typescript).**

Both the quality profiles will analyze the sources which had included, it will end up in duplicate errors.

In order to implement static code analysis only for Typescript source. All Linting rules for **Javascript needs to be disabled.**

> Default Javascript Sonarway Quality Profiles rules cannot 
>   be customized.

To disable all Javscript rules, create your own Quality Profile for Javascript disable all rules.

Configure the newly created JavaScript Quality Profile for your project.

Here attached the screenshot of my project dashboard 
[Sonarqube project dashboard with quality profile list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6WT9.png)

*This solution worked for me well, Hopefully it will help you too!!!*

Answer (score 1):

`Dsonar.ts.coverage.lcovReportPath=lcov.info`

is the command that worked for me finally for coverage addition in Sonarqube for typescript files.

Comment: is that a typo or is it actually `Dsonar` and not `sonar`?

Answer (score 0):

In the case the relative path doesn't work for you, try with the **absolute path** which was the solution for me.

```
Dsonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=src/coverage/report/lcov.info'
```

For **karma** users, do not forget to add the configuration in the `coverageReporter` which isn't setup by default:

```
coverageReporter: {
  type: 'lcov' ,
  subdir: 'report'
},
```

And here is the matching project tree simplified (Angular example):

```
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ src/
│  ├─ app
│  ├─ assets
│  ├─ coverage
│     ├─ report
│        ├─ lcov-report
│        ├─ lcov.info
│  ├─ environments
│  ├─ karma.conf.js
├─ package.json
├─ README.md
├─ ...
```

Comment: is that a typo or is it actually `Dsonar` and not `sonar`?

Comment: @AndreschSerj `On the command line of the scanner invocation using the -D or --define switch, for example: sonar-scanner -Dsonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=./coverage/lcov.info` https://docs.sonarqube.org/9.6/analyzing-source-code/test-coverage/javascript-typescript-test-coverage/